# How to show a Badge on menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I saw on some sites they have a menu and their is a small badge which shows number on the menu. Does anybody knows how that is shown. I am developing a web application using mvc and razor syntax. Now for example I have a menu "Email" and if there is any new email is received then the menu item should show "Email 1". Here "1" should be at top right of the Email menu. I was curious to know if somebody has done this and can share some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use the `data` attribute of HTML elements, and then, use `content:attr(data)` to generate a CSS only badge like this :

[image: Badge example]

Here's an example:

```css
.badged::after{
    content:attr(data-count); /* Important part */

    position:relative;    
    top:-10px;
    right:0px;

    display:inline-block;
    min-width:16px;
    height:16px;

    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    
    border:1px solid darkred;
    border-radius:10px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="badged" data-count="1">I'm badged!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/87FE9/1/

```
.e {
    width: 90px; height: 40px; background-color: rgb(50, 121, 128); line-height: 40px; text-align: center; color: white;
    margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;
}
.alert {
    position: absolute; background-color: rgb(0, 204, 255); border-radius: 1000px; width: 30px; height: 30px; text-align: center; line-height: 30px; top: 28px; left: 65px;
    display: none;
}
body,html {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    height: 100%; background-color: rgb(45, 38, 61);
}
```

it's basically **a div with huge border radius** but small width and height which make it appear a circle and it's absolutely positioned, in my case, but usually in reference to parent element and is showed or hidden via javascript.